# Is there a easy way to compile a list of tables and forms in the database

Tags: ms-access

I am creating a DBA documentation form in the database to help track changes made within the database. Currently, my form is pretty simple it has an ID, date field, table/ form name, control name, change made, and why. I want to add a validation rule or a dropdown that has a list of the tables and forms in the database but I am unsure of how to do this. Does anyone know of an easy way to do this? I want to generate a report that lists the changes made to a form/ table so it is crucial that the names are spelled right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer but I will leave the question up in case others have a similar question. I used the following query to generate a list of forms.

Select distinctRow Name
From MSysObjects
Where Type = -32768
Order By Name